# How to use spring DI constructor with dynamic parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Anyone know how to invoke beans with dynamic parameters? I was struggling with this kind of method and got stuck. Please help.

So here is the problem, I invoke the builder through @autowired in StoreService but the builder is always return this error

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I know the issue is because the parameters on constructor is not set properly, and I don't have an idea how to define the parameters on constructor to do DI. I already tried different ways, but still get the same error.

This is the code that I have done.

Config class to initiate beans.

```
@Configuration
public class BuilderConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public ObjectBuilder builder(final String title, final String filename, final String text) {
        return new ObjectBuilder(title, filename, text);
    }
}
```

ObjectBuilder class.

```
@Component
public class ObjectBuilder {

    private String title;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public ObjectBuilder(final String title, final String filename, final String text) {
        this.title= title;
        this.build(filename, text);
    }

    public void build(String filename, String text) {
        // build data
    } 

    public void publish() {
       // to publish data
    }
}
```

Class whose invoke builder class.

```
@service
public class StoreServiceImpl implements StoreService {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectBuilder builder;

    public void save(final String title, final String filename, final String text) {
       this.save(builder.publish());
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `@Component` from `ÒbjectBuilder`. Also this won't work as you would need to get the `ObjectBuilder` each time you  need it inside the `save` method. Why this complexity and simply not just create a new instance yourself. There is nothing wrong with using `new`.

Answer (score 1):

`@Scope("prototype")` means that spring inject new `ObjectBuilder` in each dependency and when you call `applicationContext.getBean("builder")` returns new `ObjectBuilder`. Also when you define bean through:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public ObjectBuilder builder(final String title, final String filename, final String text) {...
}
```

Spring expects that title, filename, text are the beans. So you can't use :

```
@Autowired
private ObjectBuilder builder;
```

I would suggest you to create a factory and use it in `StoreServiceImpl`:

***ObjectBuilderFactory.java:***

```
@Component
public class ObjectBuilderFactory {
    public ObjectBuilder create(final String title, final String filename, final String text) {
        return new ObjectBuilder(title, filename, text);
    }
}
```

***SoreServiceImpl.java:***

```
@Service
public class StoreServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectBuilderFactory builderFactory;

    public void save(final String title, final String filename, final String text) {
        ObjectBuilder builder = builderFactory.create(title, filename, text);
        builder.publish();
    }
}
```

***ObjectBuilder.java:***

```
public class ObjectBuilder {

    private String title;

    public ObjectBuilder(final String title, final String filename, final String text) {
        this.title= title;
        this.build(filename, text);
    }

    public void build(String filename, String text) {
        // build data
    }

    public void publish() {
        // to publish data
    }
}
```

In this case you can remove `BuilderConfig.java`.